# Wordpress: Package plugin with theme

Tags: wordpress, templates, plugins, themes

Okay, this may sound silly but stay with me.

I am packaging a Wordpress Premium Theme for sales in a major marketplace. The theme is heavily dependant on a couple of plugins (self-developed).

I cannot expect the buyers to manually install both my plugins before installing the theme. Now that I am packaging the themes for sale, how do I package the plugins with it?

I want the plugins to a part of the package I deliver to the buyers and the plugins should automatically install when the theme is installed.

On the other hand, I have seen Premium Theme developers packing some serious custom functionality into their themes. How is such extra functionality integrated with the themes? Can anyone link to any tutorials?

Comment: how do you require the plugin files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This class that I built with another developer should be a good solution for your problem. :)

https://github.com/thomasgriffin/TGM-Plugin-Activation

Answer (score 4):

A good way to do this is to put your plugins in a directory in your theme.  In your theme's `functions.php`...

- Require the plugin files
- For widget plugins, use the `widgets_init` action hook to call `register_widget()` for each one

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have managed to integrate one plugin into the theme.

Comment: But the second plugin has an install/uninstall scripts, database requiements and admin panels. Any ideas on how to integrate those as well?

Comment: There's a `switch_theme` action hook that will work for activation.  I don't think there's a deactivation hook for themes.